# can dc voltage and ac voltage flow on same conductor at a same time?

Tags: ac, dc, electrical

I want to know dc and ac voltage flow on same conductor at a same time ?

Comment: An AC voltage can have a DC component or vice versa

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, voltages don't flow.  Currents flow.  Voltages are measured *across* things.

Answer (score 3):

What this would look like is the standard AC sine wave that is offset to a DC value. In other words, suppose your DC value is 24 volts. Your AC sine wave, instead of oscillating about the 0 volt axis, would be oscillating around the 24 volt line. The offset is what Nick B is calling a DC component. See graphic below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, since voltages don't flow.

However, it is possible to have a DC and AC voltage superimposed on one another.  This can cause DC and AC currents to flow, depending on the load that is connected to the voltage.

Keep in mind that at any one time, there is only a single voltage.  It can be a useful abstraction to consider the voltage over time to be the DC average with AC added to it.

For example, sin(ωt) is a purely AC signal (the DC average is 0).  However, sin(ωt) + 2 is a signal that can be thought of as having a DC and AC component.

Deliberately adding a DC component to a AC signal is sometimes done deliberately.  The cable TV and phone feed in one building I'm familiar with does exactly that.  The signals are all modulated at high frequency.  When used, they will be AC coupled.  There is a power supply that adds 24 V to this signal.  That allows some devices to use the 24 V DC for power, while still receiving and transmitting on the AC bus.  The bus in this case is a large-diameter coaxial cable.